# Does OkHttp trust personal CAs?

Tags: okhttp

I am trying to connect to my webserver with Android apps which are using okhttp. The webserver is using an SSL certificate signed by my own personal CA. The CA is added to the phone/tablet, but I get the following error:

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

The server contains the complete certificate chain. Should this work in principle? Does okhttp trust added personal CAs?

The https connection works without problems in the browser and other apps not using okhttp.

Comment: Which Android version? OkHttp is impacted by this: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/changes-to-trusted-certificate.html

Comment: Thanks, I am pretty sure that is my problem. So by default google does not allow me to trust myself. Without telling me that adding a custom CA (which ist still possible) to my phone might be ignored, depending on the app developer.